# C# qyery and update an item in Json.Linq.Object

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the following dynamic object and would like to update particular token in the object. How to achieve this in C#.

[image]

and my json is as below:
[image]

I am looking for a way to update the template.learner.name object.

Here is what i tried but its throwing error:

```
                JObject template = JObject.Parse(assignment.Template.ToString());
                var learner = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LearnerTemplate>(template.ChildTokens[3]);
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you've shoot your leg by using dynamic object.

Comment: Deserialize `Template.ChildTokens[3]` to c# class object, change properties of that class object, serialize it back to json, assigne it back to `Template.ChildTokens[3]`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I am getting '"Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference"' when i try to deserialize to C# class object when i tried var learner = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LearnerTemplate>(assignment.Template.ChildTokens[3]);

Comment: Why you can not do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LearnerTemplate>(.(assignment.Template.ChildTokens[3])`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya thanks. I didnt get ChildTokens[] but it worked when i use the code as shown in my updated. Hope it is righ tone

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your code and JSON as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's policy here not to to use images for textual data, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.  A [mcve] showing the code that does not work would increase your chances of getting an answer, for why see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SelectToken](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm) function, with the `JPath` you need.

The trick here is you need to arrive to the parent, and then change child value.

I created a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jXmTex) with working version.

You have here the code:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var json = JToken.Parse(@"
        {
            'template' :
            {
              'learner' : {
                 'email' : 'a@b.com'
              }
            }
        }
        
        ");
        json.SelectToken("template.learner")["email"] = "changed";
        
        Console.WriteLine(json.SelectToken("template.learner.email"));
    }
}
```